# Changing connection string without recompile

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, database-connection

I'm working on a WinForm application. I've implemented data-access logic into a *"library project"* that I set as reference in my WinForm project. I'm using LINQ to SQL to connect to my project database, mapping the tables I use into a `dbml` file. Now I have to publish my project and change the connection string to point to the production DB.

Is it possible to change the connection string without re-compile the project?
It'll be very useful at debug-time and for maintenance...

I've tried to change it in `app.config` and also in the `Settings` file, but it seems to still point to the development DB.

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you create a minimal test case? An application as small as possible that still has the problem?

Comment: Where your connection string is defined?

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk I've created a dll project for accessing data. when i create my dbml file putting the tables i use inside it, the connection string is saved in a `settings` file and also in the `app.config` file of my "data-access-project". I'd like to specify the connection string in the project that uses as reference this dll... is it possible?

Comment: This should help you http://goneale.com/2009/03/26/untie-linq-to-sql-connection-string-from-application-settings/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution suggested in this article is very good: http://goneale.com/2009/03/26/untie-linq-to-sql-connection-string-from-application-settings/

But I decided to solve my issue in a different way.

Without modifying anyting in the `dbml` file I added in my DAO class a constructor that takes a parameter:

```
public MyDataAccessClass(string connectionString)
{
     _connString = connectionString;
}
```

then instead of using `DataClasses()` constructor to instantiate the LINQ-TO-SQL class, I replaced it with `DataClasses(_connString)`.

Now I can use the data access library where I need. The connection string will be set in `app.config` of the referencig application (or anywhere else).

Comment: The page you linked is no longer available. Could you put a summary of what it said in your answer please?